# Method RegExp.prototype.exec called on incompatible receiver

Tags: javascript

Recently, I met a trouble with `RegExp.prototype`. As normal, `RegExp.prototype` is an empty regular expression, but, I try to use `RegExp.prototype.test('')` in console , it will be wrong. Why it will show error

[image: image with error]

Comment: I know I can new RegExp .But why Array.prototype.map(function(){}) will not be error . So I troubled with RegExp.prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(RegExp.prototype.test.toString());
//RegExp.prototype.test is a native function
//if you want call this function,you should new a Regexp
console.log(new RegExp(/^$/).test(''));
```